# Specify Authentication Backend for Multi-Tenant Environment

Tags: python, django

I understand Django supports multi-tenancy by looping through all of the backends in the settings.py DATABASES object and attempting to get a username and password match. Rather than loop through all the backends, I'd like to customize the authenticate method such that I can specify the backend of which to authenticate.

So this method

```
def authenticate(request=None, **credentials):
    """
    If the given credentials are valid, return a User object.
    """
    for backend, backend_path in _get_backends(return_tuples=True):
```

would look something like this.

```
def authenticate(request=None, **credentials):
    """
    If the given credentials are valid, return a User object.
    """
    for backend, backend_path in _get_backend('contoso'):
```

Any tips or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to just wrap each authentication backend in a wrapper that checks to see if it's the right one. For example, instead of using `ModelBackend` in your [`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS) setting (note, not `DATABASES`), you'd add your own class instead.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class StrictModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        if desired_backend() == "path.to.StrictModelBackend":
            return super().authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        else:
            return None
```

Here I hardcoded the wrapper for simplicity, but if you were using more than a couple backends you'd probably instead want to dynamically create the wrapper classes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I see ModelBackend has a reference to UserModel (UserModel = get_user_model()), which inherits from QuerySet. I can use the inherited QuerySet methods to select the appropriate database.

Comment: @MitchStewart: I see, I think you were mixing up the concept of having multiple databases with having multiple authentication backends? You want to use the `ModelBackend` logic but authenticate against a specific, non-`default` database? It sounds like you've found the right solution, you just have to do your own version and make the `get()` call with the desired database.

Comment: I was able to rewrite the authenticate method in my custom subclass of ModelBackend, but now I'm running into issues maintaining state. For example, when I authenticate the user using a database other than the default one, the view decorator login_required always returns false. Moreover, after authenticating, I am again returned to the login page where self.request.user is of type AnonymousUser.

Comment: I'm going to take a step back and try a different approach. I'm going to incorporate this django add-on (https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to turn my single tenant app into a multi-tenant app.